# Firefox 29 default Accept-Language bug

Tags: firefox, session, http, i18n

Since I upgraded Firefox to version 29 it is sending the wrong `Accept-Language` header `en-US,en;q=0.5` which should be `pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3`, it was right on previous version.

I managed to fix it temporarily by going to `about:config`, searching for `intl.accept_languages` flag, changing to anything then reseting it to the default to restore the correct value, which by the way was the same before changing, so Firefox is able to send the correct `Accept-Language` header.

But there is two issues:

1. It works only on this instance of the browser, if I restart it I need to do the configuration again.
2. I can not expect all Firefox users around the world do the same, since not everyone has the required knowledgement.

I tested on my girlfriend's PC to ensure the error happens, and it is really a issue of Firefox, not only from my configuration.

It do not happens on the Windows version of Firefox, only for Linux one.

I want to know if it happens with other ones too, and if it is indeed a Firefox new bug.

Comment: I created a new bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1005640

Comment: It only happens on Firefox from Canonical repository.